# What is wrong with this code?

Tags: tables, errors

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centerline {\begin{tabular}{llr} 
\hline \hline
\cline{1-2}
Område & Area & x & y & $Ax$ & $Ay$ \\
\hline \hline
Triangeln & 157,5 & 14,83 & 6 & 2335,25 & 945 \\
Halvcirkeln & 127,17 & 5,18 & 9 & 658,78 & 1144,53 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Det genomsnittliga tiden för en period hos varje försök.}
\end{table}
```

How do I fix this? All my variables doesn't fit in the table.

Comment: 1) `{llr}` means three columns ... left,left and right aligned .... You need six columns and not 3. 
2) Use `\centering` (no argument for `\centering`) instead of `\centerline{...}`

Comment: Ahaa, what's the code for 6 columns?

Comment: @oni thank you!

Comment: could be `{llllll}` or `{lrrrrr}` etc .... Also there are columns like `p{2cm}` or `m{2cm}` ... `l` means left ... `r` means right ... `c` means centered in the cells.... `p{2cm}` is a column with automatic breaks and width of 2 cm `m{2cm}` is like p but verticlay centered

Comment: Yeah got it, btw how can I make my variables be at center in the table, I mean "Område & Area & x & y & $Ax$ & $Ay$ \\" these, they are not in center if you understand what I mean. Well "Område & Area" these are but the rest are not.

Comment: `Område & Area & \multicolumn{1}{c}{x} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{y} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$Ax$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$Ay$} \\\`

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify as many columns as you use in the table.

Do yourself a favor and learn a bit of `siunitx` for this kind of tables, so the numbers will line up perfectly. I also recommend `booktabs` for the better rules.

I lined up also the input, but it's not required: it's just easier to read the code and maybe fix faulty entries.

Note that `\centerline` is the wrong tool and a simple `\centering` declaration is better.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs} % better tables
\usepackage{siunitx}  % numeric tables and more

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=3.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=1.0]
  S[table-format=4.2]
  S[table-format=4.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Område      & {Area} & {$x$} & {$y$} & {$Ax$}  & {$Ay$} \\
\midrule
Triangeln   & 157,5  & 14,83 & 6     & 2335,25 &  945    \\
Halvcirkeln & 127,17 &  5,18 & 9     &  658,78 & 1144,53 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Det genomsnittliga tiden för en period hos varje försök.}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add more columns to your table. `\begin{tabular}{llrlll} … \end{tabular}`

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering{\begin{tabular}{llrlll} 
\hline \hline
\cline{1-2}
Område & Area & x & y & $Ax$ & $Ay$ \\
\hline \hline
Triangeln & 157,5 & 14,83 & 6 & 2335,25 & 945 \\
Halvcirkeln & 127,17 & 5,18 & 9 & 658,78 & 1144,53 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Det genomsnittliga tiden för en period hos varje försök.}
\end{table}
```